# compile ICU fully statically

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, icu

I am designing an application that should work with any language. That is why am interested in ICU. 
I would like to statically compile ICU, because my application is relatively light weight ans I need mostly UnicodeStrings and IOstreams, the rest is garbage for my purposes. I also would like to distribute my application in single .exe
I wrote the short program below to test different kind of strings.

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "unicode\unistr.h"
    #include "unicode\ustream.h"

    using namespace std;
    using namespace icu;




       int main(void)
        {
            string normal_string="Андрей";
            wstring wide_string=L"Андрей";
            UnicodeString ustr="Андрей";
            cout<<normal_string<<endl;
            wcout<<wide_string<<endl;
            cout<<ustr;
            return 0;

        }
```

I included the header files and allegedly static libraries (.lib files) in the solution of this project. It compiled, but still asked for .dll while attemting to run.
ICU [provides](http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/readme.html#UserConfig) some instructions in that regard, but I don't understand a line there.

So I just would like to include a  necessary header file and then the program compiles and links with my code and runs without any additional components
 I use MVS 2010 with the latest Intel compiler