# What to use to store Unicode (UTF-16) strings? (C++11)

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode

I ask this question in the light of the innovations that C++11 brings, namely uchar16_t/u16string.

I write an application that should have multilingual support. According to my plan the localization strings will be stored in XML as UTF-16, and retrieved with pugixml. THe strings will be used both for the GUI and generating HTML report of the computation results. Since I have understood wchar_t/wstring as being deprecated in favour of new u16string, I've planned to use u16string for storing language strings inside the program.
But since both pugixml and MFC's CString use wchar_t as underlining storage type for the Unicode, should I perhaps forget about u16string for now and instead use straightforwardly wstring?

Language-portability is crucial, platform portability doesn't matter.

I use MVS 2013 with Intel compiler.

Comment: [libicu](http://site.icu-project.org/)?

Comment: Why oh why UTF-16? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful

Comment: What is "language-portability"? If you only use one compiler, there's nothing to port.

Comment: Use UTF-8. See http://www.utf8everywhere.org/ for why.

Comment: UTF-8 Everywhere zealots are nearly as annoying as Haskell advocates. Seriously, there are reasons to use UTF-16.

Comment: @DeadMG, I think we are less annoying.. and trying to bring some order and comfort to the industry. And if there is such a reason, then certainly not in disk storage..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The encoding used for storing the data *outside the program* is the only one that matters.**

That data is likely to be used from other software. Someone will want to write those strings and they'll probably use some kind of specialised editor or *gasp* a general-purpose text editor. UTF-8 has much better support from other software than UTF-16, and that's what I would recommend and why.

Inside the program, what encoding you use doesn't matter, as long as you do it consistently and don't mix them up in stupid ways.

Obviously, if you use the same encoding inside the program as you do outside of it, you don't need to perform any conversions and the risk of mixing them up and producing [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) is not there.

The thing with pugixml using `wchar_t` is that the encoding it uses then depends on the size of `wchar_t`. If the size is 2, it uses UTF-16; if the size is 4 it uses UTF-32. pugixml also has the option to use UTF-8 with `char` by setting the [`PUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE`](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/install.html#PUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE) macro appropriately, so you can use that instead.

If you use `wchar_t` API, stick to `wstring`. Remember: since we're inside the program, it doesn't matter if it's going to be UTF-16 or UTF-32, as long as we're consistent. If you use the `char` API, stick to `string`. You could, I guess, perform conversions from `wchar_t` to `char16_t` and use `u16string`s, but that wouldn't give much benefit.

The saving and loading functions in pugixml take an `xml_encoding` parameter that lets you pick what encoding will be on the data outside the program, and that doesn't have to match what you use internally. Pick whichever you find the most convenient.

Comment: Isn't `u16string` a more modern solution?

Comment: @cubuspl42 It's still the same solution of old: `std::basic_string`. It doesn't add anything magical. It's just a fancy vector with a zero in the end. It has, for example, the disadvantage that it cannot be inserted into a standard stream without jumping through some hoops first. I added a paragraph that mentions it, anyway.

Comment: No recommendation of ICU here?

Comment: @DeadMG AFAIK the OP will just be pushing the bytes around (like, from the file straight to some MFC control), so I don't think ICU will be particularly useful. pugixml does whatever conversions are needed already.

Comment: The question was about using wstrings/wchar_t despite u16string being availible. as far as i understood from your answer in my case I lose nothing from using wstring instead of u16string

Comment: UTF-16 is native for Windows AFAIK. I don't want to mess with conversions and locales. Just read in and store as is

Comment: I considered icu, but that would require to use dynamic libraries that weigh twice as my application, because i couldnt find a way to compile and link them statically under windows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429764/compile-icu-fully-statically

Comment: @AndreyPro WinAPI wide functions are *nearly* UTF-16, because UTF-16 is NOT fixed length. Check out this: http://www.utf8everywhere.org

Comment: @cubuspl42: WinAPI moved from UCS-2 to UTF-16 a long time ago, they support surrogates.Stop spamming that UTF-8 everywhere shit. It's not helpful.

Comment: @cubuspl42 which WinAPI functions fail to handle UTF-16 surrogate pairs?

Comment: @cubuspl42 the 90s called. They wanted their UCS-2 back. Windows has used UTF-16 since Windows 2000.

Comment: @cubuspl42 you know what's more ridiculous? If you had actually *read* the page on the other side of that link you people keep spamming everywhere like mad men, you would have already known that Windows uses UTF-16, because it is written there. You would also have learned that fixed-length is an irrelevant property for most operations.

Comment: @DeadMG and others. Sorry, my bad. But despite that, I think that UTF-8 should be preffered over UTF-16 and there are many reasons for that, that are put together on one site. That's just my opinion and I don't think it's shit.

Comment: @cubuspl42 FWIW, I agree (and I do mention that in the answer). I just get annoyed by this blind preaching I see everywhere.

Comment: @cubuspl42 the problem is that you try to impose your opinion on others. you remind Yehova's wutnesses to some extend.